# JSON não retorna dados do banco MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, json

Fiz uma aplicação bem simples pra buscar projetos por estado no banco de dados. Porém, o JSON não exibe nenhum erro, mas também não retorna nada. Imagino que o problema possa estar no GET. Sabem o que pode ser? Seguem os códigos abaixo:

Código do formulário HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:60px">
        <h2>Buscar projetos por estado</h2><br><br>
        <h4>Escolha o estado desejado: </h4><br/>
        <form action="consultarEstado.php" method="get">
        <select name="estado" id="estado">
            <option value="AC">Acre</option>
            <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
            <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
            <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
            <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
            <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
            <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
            <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
            <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
            <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
            <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
            <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
            <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
            <option value="PA">Pará</option>
            <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
            <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
            <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
            <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
            <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
            <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
            <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
            <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
            <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
            <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
            <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
            <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
            <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
        </div>
```

Construindo o JSON:

```
<?php

include './Classes/Conexao.php';
include './Classes/DAO/UsuarioDAO.php';

if ($_GET)) {
    $estado = $_GET['estado'];
    $UsuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    $consulta = $UsuarioDAO->consultarEstado($estado);

    if ($consulta == true) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($consulta); $i++) {
            $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

            $respostas [] = array (
                'id_projeto' => $linha['id_projeto'],
                'municipio' => $linha['municipio'],
                'estado' => $linha['estado'],
                'nome' => $linha['nome'],
            );   
        }
    }

echo json_encode($respostas);
} else {
    echo 'Nenhum parâmetro foi passado na URL.';
}

?>
```

Função:

```
public function consultarEstado($estado) {
        $sql = "SELECT id_projeto, municipio, estado, nome FROM projeto WHERE estado = '$estado'";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexao->getCon(), $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
            return $resultado; 
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando o estado via post e está tentando lê com get, tente:

```html
<?php

include './Classes/Conexao.php';
include './Classes/DAO/UsuarioDAO.php';

if ($_POST)) {
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $UsuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    $consulta = $UsuarioDAO->consultarEstado($estado);

    if ($consulta == true) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($consulta); $i++) {
            $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

            $respostas [] = array (
                'id_projeto' => $linha['id_projeto'],
                'municipio' => $linha['municipio'],
                'estado' => $linha['estado'],
                'nome' => $linha['nome'],
            );   
        }
    }

echo json_encode($respostas);
} else {
    echo 'Nenhum parâmetro foi passado na URL.';
}

?>
```

Ou então mude o method do seu form para GET no seu arquivo HTML.

Comment: O problema persiste. Eu já tinha feito o teste com GET e com POST e os dois continuam sem me retornar nada.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que o problema estava sendo causado pelos caracteres especiais dos dados. Coloquei utf8_encode em cada linha do vetor e consegui retornar os valores, apesar dos caracteres especiais ainda precisarem ser tratados.

```
<?php

include './Classes/Conexao.php';
include './Classes/DAO/UsuarioDAO.php';

if ($_GET) {
    $estado = $_GET['estado'];
    $UsuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    $consulta = $UsuarioDAO->consultarEstado($estado);

    if ($consulta == true) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($consulta); $i++) {
            $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

            $respostas [] = array (
                'id_projeto' => utf8_encode($linha['id_projeto']),
                'municipio' => utf8_encode($linha['municipio']),
                'estado' => utf8_encode($linha['estado']),
                'nome' => utf8_encode($linha['nome']),
            );   
        }
    }

echo json_encode($respostas);
} else {
    echo 'Nenhum parâmetro foi passado na URL.';
}

?>
```

Comment: Ok, mas você não devia precisar fazer isso. Possíveis problemas: seu HTML não está sendo servido como UTF-8, ou seu formulário não está sendo postado como UTF-8, ou a codificação da conexão com o banco não está sendo setada, ou a *collation* da sua tabela de banco de dados está errada.